# How to disable drawer indicator movement in Android?

Tags: android

The navigation drawer icon on the top left is sliding in a bit when the navigation drawer is open. Can I disable this little animation so the icon stands still on its place all the time?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it. 
In your `onCreate` function, when you create your `ActionBarDrawerToggle` 
override your `onDrawerSlide` function like that:

`@Override
public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {}`

deleting the `super` call, you delete the slide movement.